# How to handle app versions in real-time multiplayer using Google Play Games?

Tags: android, google-play-games

Here is the example:

- First game version (v1) - initial multiplayer features.
- Second game version (v2) - fixed minor bugs, remains compatible with v1.
- Third game version (v3) - added some new gameplay mechanics, this version is NOT compatible with v1 and v2.

In this situation, I want Play Games Services to allow auto-connect for versions v1 and v2, but players on v3 should only connect to other v3.

How do I do this with Google Play Games Real-time multiplayer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RoomConfig has a variant field that is used to match players.  The variant value must exactly match in order to connect players. For more information see: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomConfig.Builder.html#setVariant(int)

When building the room your code would look something like (where *GameVersion* is the version of your game):

```
    int minPlayers = 2;
    int maxPlayers = 2;
    long bitmask = 0;
    Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(minPlayers, maxPlayers, bitmask);
    // build the room config
    RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
    roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(am)
    .setVariant(GameVersion < 3 ? 1 : 3);

    RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
    // create room:
   Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, roomConfig);
```

Comment: is it really the only way? If I use variant for app version, then how can I filter by all my game modes too? deathmatching, capture the flag etc, variant is for that right? If variant was a string it would be easy... "modeDM"+AppVersion.ToString()